# r: Summarise for rowSums after group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I've tried searching a number of posts on SO but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and I imagine the solution is quite simple. I'm trying to group a dataframe by one variable and figure the mean of several variables within that group.

Here is what I am trying:

```
head(airquality)
target_vars = c("Ozone","Temp","Solar.R")
airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% select(target_vars) %>% summarise(rowSums(.))
```

But I get the error that my lenghts don't match. I've tried variations using `mutate` to create the column or `summarise_all`, but neither of these seem to work. I need the row sums within group, and then to compute the mean within group (yes, it's nonsensical here).

Also, I want to use `select` because I'm trying to do this over just certain variables.

I'm sure this could be a duplicate, but I can't find the right one.

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**
Sorry, my original question was not clear. Imagine the grouping variable is the calendar month, and we have `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`. I'd like to know, within `month`, what was the average of the sums of `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`. So if we have 12 months, the result would be a 12x1 dataframe. Here is an example if we just had 1 month:

```
Month v1 v2 v3 Sum 
1      1  1  0   2
1      1  1  1   3
1      1  0  0   3
```

Then the result would be:

```
Month  Average
1           8/3
```

Comment: Your description, "group a dataframe by one variable and figure the mean of several variables within that group," sounds like you want `airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% select(target_vars) %>% summarise_all(mean, na.rm = T)`. It doesn't sound like `rowSums` are needed at all.

Comment: Why would you need to `group_by` if you're calculating `rowSums`?

Comment: @vashts85 when you calculate `Average` are you dividing by the number of columns? Or the number of rows? It seems some of the answers are dividing by the number of columns.

Comment: I suppose it's the number of rows. So month 1 has 3 rows, and the sum of each row is 8, so you divided 8 by 3.

Comment: @vashts85 it looks Jimbou is dividing by number of columns (perhaps Jimbou can add confirmation here). I recommend calculating the mean of rowSums for the 5th month to see which answer gives you the expected answer. The answers all differ so you'll have to decide which one provides the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
airquality %>% 
  select(Month, target_vars) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Month) %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(n=length(unique(key)),
            Sum=sum(value, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(Average=Sum/n)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Month     n   Sum  Average
  <int> <int> <int>    <dbl>
1     5     3  7541 2513.667
2     6     3  8343 2781.000
3     7     3 10849 3616.333
4     8     3  8974 2991.333
5     9     3  8242 2747.333
```

The idea is to convert the data from wide to long using `tidyr::gather()`, then group by `Month` and calculate the sum and the average.

Comment: Looks possibly interesting but check my answer and explain why out numbers disagree. I think my answer is more clearly correct, at least in a numeric sense if not being dplyr-isch.

Comment: Can you explain the `gather` line? I haven't really used `gather` or `spread` so I'm not familiar with their parameters.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) or [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/). There it is much better explained al I could ever do.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to deliver what you want. It's regular R. The `sapply` function keeps the months separated by "name". The `sum` function applied to each dataframe will not keep the column sums separate. (Correction # 2: used only target_vars):

```
sapply( split( airquality[target_vars], airquality$Month), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
    5     6     7     8     9 
 7541  8343 10849  8974  8242
```

If you wanted the per number of variable results, then you would divide by the number of variables:

```
sapply( split( airquality[target_vars], airquality$Month), sum, na.rm=TRUE)/
                                                           (length(target_vars))
       5        6        7        8        9 
2513.667 2781.000 3616.333 2991.333 2747.333
```

Comment: Plase comment on the output of `sum(airquality[,-5],na.rm = T)` and `sum(sapply( split( airquality, airquality$Month), sum, na.rm=TRUE))`. i think its the question if you add the Month variable to the result or not...In my solution I don't. In contrast your result includes the sum of Month.

Comment: You are correct, but our methods still don't agree. It's interesting that you can see the error in mine bur yours is rather opaque, so I'm unable to debug you methods, which I still think are wrong ... somewhere.

Comment: Hm why you think my solution is opaque?

Comment: Because I think it's wrong (at least it gets a different final result than an R action which I think is rather clear), and I cannot follow the logic to figure out where the error is. I think one would need to look at each intermediate result and determine whether it is actually what is intended.  So that to me is "opaque".

Comment: @Jimbou Take a look at `sum( aq[ aq$Month==5, !grepl("Month", colnames(aq) ) ], na.rm=TRUE)  # [1] 8397.3` and at `sum( aq[ aq$Month==5, !grepl("Month", colnames(aq) ) ], na.rm=TRUE)/5   #[1] 1679.46` and tell me why your answers are different.

Comment: This is easy. My answer is different because I considered only the columns using the `target_vars = c("Ozone","Temp","Solar.R")` as defined in the question. Take a look at `sum( aq[ aq$Month==5, target_vars ], na.rm=TRUE) [1] 7541`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)   # forgot this in original post
airquality %>%
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  nest(Ozone, Temp, Solar.R, .key=newcol) %>%
  mutate(newcol = map_dbl(newcol, ~mean(rowSums(.x, na.rm=TRUE))))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  # Month   newcol
  # <int>    <dbl>
# 1     5 243.2581
# 2     6 278.1000
# 3     7 349.9677
# 4     8 289.4839
# 5     9 274.7333
```

I've never encountered a situation where all the answers disagreed. Here's some validation (at least I think) for the 5th month

```
airquality %>%
  filter(Month == 5) %>%
  select(Ozone, Temp, Solar.R) %>%
  mutate(newcol = rowSums(., na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(sum5 = sum(newcol), mean5 = mean(newcol))

#   sum5    mean5
# 1 7541 243.2581
```